# image element not resolving in Internet Explorer 11 but does in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

Image element similar to the following...

```
<img src="file.asp?type=image&name=test"/>
```

shows as a small box with an x in it in IE 11.  If I try to navigate directly to file.asp?type=image&name=test in IE, Sharepoint opens.

The same page renders the image (jpg) correctly in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the console/network (F12)? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to find if there is any error /exception using developer tool (F12) or Fiddler, If nothing found then check for the image format.

Some times Internet Explorer is unable to display images which are encoded in the CMYK format rather than the regular RGB format. 
CMYK (Cyan-Magenta-Yellow-blacK) is a color system representing 147 colors defined by the Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) Specification used for printing.

The easiest solution would be to open the image using image editors such as Adobe Photoshop,Gimp and convert it to RGB image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was file.asp was sending Content Type as "image/jpg".  Firefox had no problem with this, but IE did.  Changed the Content Type to "image/jpeg" and IE displays the image now.